How can I exclude the base directory from a recursive glob in Python?
When using glob.glob("D:/TEST/*"), we don't get D:/TEST/ in the result.
With  glob.glob("D:/TEST/**"), idem.
But when doing glob.glob("D:/TEST/**", recursive=True) we get all the files and subdirectories recursively, as desired, but we also get the base directory D:/TEST/. It seems unnatural to list the base dir, since it is not the case for non-recursive glob.
Is there an option built-in in glob to avoid the base dir in the result? (other option than manually removing the base dir in the result of glob?)

When I try that I get the content of the base directory listed in each case, as I would expect. I am not sure why you do not expect that in each case, as that is normal processing for the command line command it is emulating.

* generally matches zero-or-more characters (meaning, zero is explicitly part of the set). Is it then not reasonable for ** to match zero elements?

...That said, there are other ways to recursively descend from a directory that don't involve ** at all. Is there a particular reason your question is focused only on glob.glob and not inclusive of approaches that don't use it?

@OldBoy What do you mean by "content of the base directory"? I am not talking about content of base dir, but base dir itself.

@OldBoy import glob; print(list(glob.glob("E:\\temp\\*"))) ['E:\\temp\\bar.txt', 'E:\\temp\\foo']. The list does not contain E:\\temp itself.

@CharlesDuffy With * we don't get E:\\temp in my last comment. Why do we get E:\\temp when using **? Do you see what I mean?

I see what you mean, but I don't see it being an on-topic question. We care about collecting solutions to narrow, specific, practical problems, not about understanding them (which is often a matter of history or accident). If you want to know if upstream considers it a bug they can fix without breaking backwards compatibility, search and then file a ticket in the Python bugtracker, but almost certainly it would be a compatibility break, so inconsistency though it may be, it's one the language is arguably locked into maintaining going forward.

Why? You'd have to go back in to to when ** was added in Python 3.5 and ask the library designers.

As I said before, that matches what you would expect to see at the command line. But as @CharlesDuffy points out, this is really not on topic for this forum.

You are asking on the history of the behavior of glob(), and it's off topic as others commented. Anyway, using the ** pattern with recursive=False will result an undefined behavior. And the reason why the ** pattern covers the base directory is that UNIX systems work like that. In a bash shell, try shopt -s globstar; for e in ./** ; do echo $e; done.

@relent95 I think you can post this as an answer. I just edited my question to emphasize on the how (that's my real goal ultimately).

@CharlesDuffy I edited to emphasize on my real actual problem, which is how (and not why). Of course we can manually remove an item in a list, but I wanted to know if there is an option built-in in glob to avoid the base dir.

If you just care about a solution, consider using the pathlib equivalent to the call (rglob('*')), which doesn't have this problem.

I think you can post this as an answer @CharlesDuffy.

As currently written, the question is on-topic.

We can see from the source code to the glob module that the set of available flags is quite limited. However, glob.glob isn't the only way to recursively scan a directory tree and return names that match a fnmatch/glob-style pattern.

Consider using pathlib's rglob instead (since it returns Path objects, we're using str() to transform back to regular strings; but for a fair set of cases you could just directly use the Paths):
import pathlib

all_test_filenames = [ str(p) for p in pathlib.Path(r'D:/TEST').rglob('*') ]

...mind, in general, I'd only use a glob()-style tool when you actually want to filter for names that match a pattern; in most scenarios where one just wants to recursively find all files and directories within a subtree, os.walk() (or its newer, TOCTOU-attack-resistant cousin os.fwalk()) is better suited.
